# Why do expressions on generic types reference the constraint type instead of the runtime type?

Tags: c#, generics, linq-expressions

The easiest way to ask this is to show the example (LinqPad) code that demonstrates the issue at hand:

```
void Main()
{
    GetProp<IFace>().DeclaringType.Dump(); // iface
    GetProp<C>().DeclaringType.Dump(); // iface
    GetProp().DeclaringType.Dump(); // c
}

public interface IFace { int A { get; set; } }

public class C : IFace { public int A { get; set; } }

public PropertyInfo GetProp<T>() where T : IFace
{
    return ExtractProperty((T x) => x.A);
}

public PropertyInfo GetProp()
{
    return ExtractProperty((C x) => x.A);
}

private PropertyInfo ExtractProperty<T, V>(Expression<Func<T, V>> exp)
{
    return (PropertyInfo) ((MemberExpression) exp.Body).Member;
}
```

I am intrigued by why `GetProp<C>` uses returns a property on `IFace` instead of a property on `C`. Can anyone explain this behavior? Looking at the `IL code`, I can see that the generic version of `GetProp<T>` uses ldtoken on the `IFace` type, but why is it implemented this way? Can anyone point me to a justification or spec for this behavior?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because member lookup is done at compile time.

The compiler binds `x.A` in your lambda to the `A` property in the interface.

This is specified in §7.4 of the spec:

> A member lookup of a name N with K type parameters in a type T is processed as follows:
>
> - First, a set of accessible members named N is determined:
>
>   - If T is a type parameter, then the set is the union of the sets of accessible members named N in each of the types specified as a primary constraint or secondary constraint (§10.1.5) for T, along with the set of accessible members named N in object.

Comment: _"named N in object"_ - what object ?

Comment: @RoyiNamir: The type `System.Object`.